# ActiveRecord `includes` not caching data in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, activerecord, heroku

I'm using Rails 4.2 with Heroku

My understanding of the `includes` function of ActiveRecord is that it fetches all the related data upfront, so it doesn't have to do the extra queries later when you call on the relation.

I'm seeing it fetch the related data, but in production (on Heroku) I'm also seeing it fetch the data again each time I call the relation. Why is this and how can I fix it?

This only happens in production, not in development.

Here's the function I'm observing this in:

```
  def max_outcome_scores()
    scores = Hash.new(0)
    logger.info '*** Running max_outcome_score ***'
    language_progresses.with_updates.
        includes(:progress_marker).find_each do |progress|
      scores[progress.progress_marker.topic_id] += progress.progress_marker.weight  * ProgressMarker.spread_text.keys.max
    end
    logger.info '*** Finished max_outcome_score ***'
    return scores
  end
```

The function works as expected, but there's too many database queries. Here's what I'm seeing in the logs:

```
2016-07-13T06:55:30.304893+00:00 app[web.1]: *** Running max_outcome_score ***
2016-07-13T06:55:30.308102+00:00 app[web.1]:   LanguageProgress Load (2.4ms)  SELECT  "language_progresses".* FROM "language_progresses" INNER JOIN "progress_updates" ON "progress_updates"."language_progress_id" = "language_progresses"."id" WHERE "language_progresses"."state_language_id" = $1  ORDER BY "language_progresses"."id" ASC LIMIT 1000  [["state_language_id", 209]]
2016-07-13T06:55:30.308882+00:00 app[web.1]:   ↳ app/models/state_language.rb:104:in `max_outcome_scores'
2016-07-13T06:55:30.313090+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "progress_markers".* FROM "progress_markers" WHERE "progress_markers"."id" IN (70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 130, 80, 81, 82, 98, 99, 100, 101, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 131, 89, 95, 96, 97, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129)
2016-07-13T06:55:30.314067+00:00 app[web.1]:   ↳ app/models/state_language.rb:104:in `max_outcome_scores'
2016-07-13T06:55:30.317657+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "progress_markers".* FROM "progress_markers" WHERE "progress_markers"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 71]]
2016-07-13T06:55:30.318379+00:00 app[web.1]:   ↳ app/models/state_language.rb:105:in `block in max_outcome_scores'
2016-07-13T06:55:30.318730+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "progress_markers".* FROM "progress_markers" WHERE "progress_markers"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 71]]
2016-07-13T06:55:30.319448+00:00 app[web.1]:   ↳ app/models/state_language.rb:105:in `block in max_outcome_scores'
2016-07-13T06:55:30.319872+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "progress_markers".* FROM "progress_markers" WHERE "progress_markers"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 75]]
2016-07-13T06:55:30.320580+00:00 app[web.1]:   ↳ app/models/state_language.rb:105:in `block in max_outcome_scores'
2016-07-13T06:55:30.320953+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "progress_markers".* FROM "progress_markers" WHERE "progress_markers"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 77]]
2016-07-13T06:55:30.321671+00:00 app[web.1]:   ↳ app/models/state_language.rb:105:in `block in max_outcome_scores'
2016-07-13T06:55:30.322226+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "progress_markers".* FROM "progress_markers" WHERE "progress_markers"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 103]]
2016-07-13T06:55:30.322938+00:00 app[web.1]:   ↳ app/models/state_language.rb:105:in `block in max_outcome_scores'
2016-07-13T06:55:30.323543+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "progress_markers".* FROM "progress_markers" WHERE "progress_markers"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 60]]
2016-07-13T06:55:30.324251+00:00 app[web.1]:   ↳ app/models/state_language.rb:105:in `block in max_outcome_scores'
2016-07-13T06:55:30.324966+00:00 app[web.1]: *** Finished max_outcome_score ***
```

I've configured the logs to output the line in the code which generates the query. Line 104 is the line with `includes` and line 105 is the line inside the `find-each` block.

Comment: doesn't this mean it's fetching it from cache and took 0 time? `CACHE (0.0ms) `

Comment: huh, maybe! But why then is it expressed as an SQL query. It looks like it's hitting the database?

Comment: Good question - to which I'd also like to know the answer... :D Just it possibly isn't as bad as at first thought...

Comment: Maybe Heroku chooses bypass ActiveRecord's caching and do it's own intercepting queries from ActiveRecord.

Comment: If someone could confirm that theory in an answer I'd accept that answer.

Comment: Usually there's no query (also no CACHE query) if you preload the records.

Can you show us your model code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that, even though ActiveRecord does collect all the necessary data up front, when it is asked for data that it would otherwise need to go to the database to get, it still builds the relevant query, but instead of hitting the database with it, it just pulls the data up from cache. Then it logs the query it built, but didn't use on the database.

Seeing these queries may in some circumstances be useful for testing and debugging, but most of the time I find they just clog up the logs.

Raphael provides a way to [suppress this logging](http://heliom.ca/blog/posts/disable-rails-cache-logging). Put this code in a ruby file in `config/initializers`

```
# Create logger that ignores messages containing “CACHE”
class CacheFreeLogger < ::Logger
  def debug(message, *args, &block)
    super unless message.include? 'CACHE'
  end
end

# Overwrite ActiveRecord’s logger
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(
  CacheFreeLogger.new(STDOUT)) unless Rails.env.test?
```